# Écrit-on « à qui je dois » ou « à qui dois-je »

Tags: grammaire, questions

Dans une discussion avec une amie qui écrivait un mail, on s'est demandé s'il faut écrire

> Savez-vous qui je dois contacter ?

Ou

> Savez-vous qui dois-je contacter ?

Je pencherai pour la première, est-ce juste ? De plus, contrairement à beaucoup de questions sur le français, je n'ai pas trouvé de réponse en tapant sur mon moteur de recherche préféré !

Comment: « Connaissez-vous la personne à contacter ? » car on ne sait pas une personne, on la connaît. « Savez-vous quelle est la personne à contacter ? » sera cependant souvent utilisé, car on ne se réfère pas à une personne, mais à sa fonction. « Savez-vous qui dois-je contacter ? » indique que vous n'êtes pas certain que la personne que vous interrogez connaît la réponse et peut être entendu ainsi : « Qui dois-je contacter, le savez-vous ? » ce qui rend votre première expression maladroite/infantile : « Qui je dois contacter, le savez-vous ? » au lieu …

Comment: … de « Quelle est la personne à contacter, le savez-vous ? »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forme interrogative est fournie par "savez-vous". Le reste de la phrase n'a pas à utiliser l'inversion du sujet. Seule la première forme est donc correcte. Ça peut être plus clair avec une autre phrase, voisine:

> Savez-vous ce que je dois faire?

On voit ici tout de suite que la double inversion est incorrecte:

> Savez-vous ce que dois-je faire?

Comment: 1. Pourquoi peut-on ou non analyser la phrase plutôt comme une forme de discours rapporté : « Je me demande : qui dois-je contacter ? » ? 2. Je trouve que « Savez-vous ce que dois-je faire? (x) » est absolument faux mais je ne peux dire la même chose de la phrase en question ; pourquoi ? 3. Est-on certain que ce qui est évident dans l'exemple choisi correspond parfaitement grammaticalement et syntaxiquement à la phrase en question ? Merci.

Answer (score 1):

à l'écrit on utilise la première forme pour une affirmation.

> Pour résoudre ... , je dois contacter le service client.

la seconde pour une question

> Pour résoudre ... , dois-je contacter le ministre ?

Dans le cas présent, `savez-vous` entraine déjà la forme interrogative, les deux possibilités me paraissent acceptable. La seconde forme est plus formelle.

Comment: Oui mais il y a : « savez-vous qui ... » devant !